# ICS gui error on view size

Tags: android, user-interface, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am building an app that has a pop up appear at a certain time that takes ove the screen and pauses the background activity.  On older versions of android this pop up view works fine, but on ICS the top of the pop up is cut off.  I have tried many things to fix it, but it only serves to mess up the view in the older versions of Android.  Has anyone else had such an error?  It seems that ICS miscalculates the size of the screen and sets the top of the screen to be much farther up.

```
ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) parent.getWindow().peekDecorView();
    ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) root.getChildAt(0);
    int title = 0;
    if (group.getChildAt(0) instanceof ViewGroup)
        title += group.getChildAt(0).getTop();
```

This is how I figure out where the top of the screen is.  This works in older Android but not ICS.

Answer (score 1):

I would say there is an easier way to create a popup. Also the top of your activity is always at y = 0.

Comment: I know that, but I don't understand why the top expands past the size of the screen on ICS specifically